# PrivateRoute is not a Route component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone please help me to get rid of this error?

> Error : [PrivateRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

PrivateRoute.js :

```
import React from "react"
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContex"

export default function PrivateRoute({ element: Element, ...rest }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      element={currentUser ? <Element {...rest} /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
    />
  )
}
```

App.js :

```
import Signup from "./components/signup"
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap"
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from './components/AuthContex'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard"
import Login from "./components/Login"
import ForgotPassword from "./components/ForgotPassword"
import UpdateProfile from "./components/UpdateProfile"

function App() {
  return (
    <Container
      className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
      style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
     >
      <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }}>
        <Router>
          <AuthProvider>
            <Routes>
              <PrivateRoute path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/update-profile" element={<UpdateProfile />} />
              <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
            </Routes>
          </AuthProvider>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </Container>
  )
}

function PrivateRoute({ element, ...rest }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  // Redirect to login if not authenticated
  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }
```

// Render the element if authenticated
return <Route {...rest} element={element} />;
}

```
export default App`
```

I am trying to create a signup page using firebase authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-router is very strict about what can be a child of `<Routes>`. You cannot put any custom component as a child, even if that child renders a `<Route>`. So you will need to redesign your `PrivateRoute` component to work *inside* the `<Route>`. For example:

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()

  if (currentUser) {
    return children;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />
  }
}
```

Used like:

```
<AuthProvider>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute><Dashboard /></PrivateRoute>} />
    <Route path="/update-profile" element={<UpdateProfile />} />
    // ...
```